# How to use custom InputMethod without changing it in system settings

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, ime

I have a View (WebView actually), where I need to use a special input method (transparent keyboard). Is it possible to use custom InputMethod for this view without changing it in system settings?

Answer (score 0):

No Application can't change the input method it can be done only through system settings. Check my other [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15976837/calling-inputmethodmanager-setinputmethodibinder-token-string-id-outside-the/17084916#17084916) for a similar question for more detail.